# Flink BlockElement Exception when updating to version 1.14.2

Tags: apache-flink, siddhi

Before, everything works well with flink 1.13.1, lately we update it to flink 1.14.2, the following code is **run:** and it throws this exception:

```
<T> DataStream<Tuple3<String, String, T>> returnsInternal(SiddhiOperatorContext siddhiContext, String[] executionPlanIds) {
    if (createdDataStream == null) {
        DataStream<Tuple2<StreamRoute, Object>> mapped = this.dataStream.map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<StreamRoute, Object>, Tuple2<StreamRoute, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<StreamRoute, Object> map(Tuple2<StreamRoute, Object> value) throws Exception {
                if (executionPlanIds != null && executionPlanIds.length != 0) {
                    for (String executionPlanId : executionPlanIds) {
                        if (!executionPlanId.isEmpty()
                                && siddhiContext.getExecutionPlan(executionPlanId).IsUsedStream(value.f0.getInputStreamId())) {
                            value.f0.addExecutionPlanId(executionPlanId);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }
        });
        
        createdDataStream = SiddhiStreamFactory.createDataStream(siddhiContext, mapped);
    }

    return createdDataStream;
}
```

The **exception**  and **callstack** are as follows:

> org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The
> implementation of the BlockElement is not serializable. The object
> probably contains or references non serializable fields.
>
> at
> org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:164)
> at
> org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:69)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2139)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:203)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.map(DataStream.java:577)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.siddhi.ExecutionSiddhiStream.ExecutionSiddhiStreamBase.returnsInternal(ExecutionSiddhiStreamBase.java:135)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.siddhi.ExecutionSiddhiStream.ExecutionSiddhiStreamBase.returnsInternal(ExecutionSiddhiStreamBase.java:123)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.siddhi.ExecutionSiddhiStream.ExecutionSiddhiStream.returnAsRow(ExecutionSiddhiStream.java:180)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.siddhi.ExecutionSiddhiStream.ExecutionSiddhiStream.returnAsRowWithQueryId(ExecutionSiddhiStream.java:165)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.siddhi.SiddhiCEPITCase.testSimplePojoStreamAndReturnRowWithQueryId(SiddhiCEPITCase.java:245)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
> at
> org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
> at
> org.apache.flink.util.TestNameProvider$1.evaluate(TestNameProvider.java:45)
> at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366) at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293) at
> org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
> at
> org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
> at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413) at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at
> com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
> org.apache.flink.configuration.description.TextElement at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
> at
> org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:632)
> at
> org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:143)
> ... 45 more

So, why is there a problem and what's the difference between 1.13.1&1.14.0，how can we fix this problem?

Comment: Did you also change the version of siddhi?

Comment: no, just flink version. BTW, it's forked from https://github.com/haoch/flink-siddhi, we have imgrate it to flink 1.13.5

Comment: Is BlockElement one of your application classes? What does it look like? I'm not sure what changed in Flink 1.14, but we should be able to figure out why this class isn't serializable.

Comment: None explicit use BlockElement or TextElemet etc..., but I guess may be it's used in some frame classes inclued in the program. Where is BlockElement or TextElement usually used and for what？

Comment: I dug a bit deeper and discovered that BlockElement, etal are used by Flink to provide rich descriptions of Flink configuration options. I'm guessing flink-siddhi is doing something unusual, perhaps using an internal API that has changed, and the result is that you're now inadvertently trying to serialize a class that was never meant to be serialized.

Comment: BlockElement (and related classes) are used to build up HTML descriptions of Flink's configuration options that are automatically generated and included in the docs. This is not something intended to end up in user applications.

Comment: @DavidAnderson,  i write the answer as followings, please tell me if i'm right.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,David Anderson. This should be a bug introduced by the latest flink commit of file [flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/ExecutionConfig.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/9e0e0929b86c372c9243daad9d654af9e7718708#diff-7a439abdf207cf6da8aa6c147b38c1346820fe786afbf652bc614fc377cdf238)

Diff the file, we can find TextElement is used here where ClosureCleanerLevel is is used as a memeber of Serializable ExecutionConfig.

[TextElement in ClosureCleanerLevel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky3d8.png)

In Flink Siddhi, ExecutionConfig is serialized which is used to serilize flink data to siddhi type on every taskmanager, so that should be the cause.

The simplest way to verify the problem is running code as followings in flink 1.13.5 and 1.14.0, the exception is reproduced in 1.14.0 . And the diff between 1.13.5 and 1.14.0 is only lates commit.

```java
@Test
public void testExecutionConfigSerializable() throws Exception {
    ExecutionConfig config = new ExecutionConfig();
    ClosureCleaner.clean(config, ExecutionConfig.ClosureCleanerLevel.RECURSIVE, true);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a bug. Please report it at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK/.

Comment: flink issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-25444?jql=project%20%3D%20FLINK%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22API%20%2F%20Core%22 @DavidAnderson thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Note that plain Java serialization still works for the ExecutionConfig, it is just the ClosureCleaner that rejects it because it does very strict checks w.r.t. serializability.

As such, the underlying problem could be that the closure of your map function is unnecessarily large.
The SiddhiOperatorContext that you pass into the method will become part of the map functiosn closure, so you could check whether you can minimize the size of that context such that it no longer relies on an ExecutionConfig.